Triangle inequality on a direct sum of Lebesgue spaces
I think a priori it is known that for $1 \leq p, q < \infty$ we have that  $||(\hspace{0.1cm},)||: L^p(E) \times L^q(E) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $, defined as $||(f, g)|| = (||f||^2_{L^p} + ||g||^2_{L^q})^{\frac{1}{2}}$, is a norm on the direct sum of Lebesgue spaces $L^p(E) \times L^q(E)$, but I can't manage to prove the triangle inequality for this norm.
I've tried standard tricks like that $|f + g|^p \leq 2^p (|f|^p + |g|^p)$ but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Can you assume the triangle inequality for the euclidian norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$? Because in your case, $\lVert (f, g) \rVert =\left \lVert \big(\lVert f \rVert_{L^p}, \lVert g \rVert_{L^q}\big)^\top\right \rVert_2$.
